# How to use 5 static ip addresses with virgin media broad band

Tags: network, nat, firewall, wan, pfsense

I have installed virgin media business broadband and the package comes with 5 static ips. These IP are GRE tunnels from the HITRON router to virgin.
the IP addresses are for example
66.66.66.65 - 66.66.66.70
255.255.255.248

with
66.66.66.65 / 29 being the LAN Gateway (HITRON router)

I have a PFSENSE firewall between the gateway with WAN setup
static IPv4        66.66.66.70 / 29
upstream gateway   66.66.66.65

How do I use the other static addresses (66.66.66.66 - 66.66.66.69)?

My assumption is to just manually set a device / or router to another one of the static ips assigned then plug it into the HITRON router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either

- connect a switch/VLAN to the handover port (on the ISP router) and connect devices using your IP addresses directly or
- assign all addresses to your pfSense firewall and map/translate the public addresses to private addresses behind the firewall/in your DMZ

Comment: Do you have a hint on how to assign all the addresses to my pfSense firewall.  I tried connecting another cable from the Hitron modem / router to the same pfSense box but on a different port, created a new wan for each with one of the static ip's but the upstream gateway ip creates an error as its used in the origional wan.
I did connect a device directly to the Hitron router with one of the static ips manually entered and the gateway set to the hitron router and this worked for network connection.

Comment: Simply add more/secondary addresses to the interface you have (no experience with pfSense, but that's the usual way to do it).

Comment: Thanks Zac67. I'm going to do a bit of research on how to do that with pfSense.